# "Correct" way to create relations from a request in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Sample post request to controller:

```json
{
  "card": 1,
  "cardPot": 6,
  "purchases": [
    {
      "description": "groceries",
      "amount": "40.60",
      "transaction_date": "17/02/2022",
      "statement_reference": "10076608",
      "statement_description": "SAINSBURYS              ",
      "reimbursements": [
        {
          "amount": "19.00",
          "pot": 3
        },
        {
          "amount": "21.60",
          "pot": 7
        },
      ],
      "spread": false
    }, 
    ....
  ]
}
```

Purchase has many reimbursements, Reimbursement belongs to purchase...

In my controller I'm doing:

```rb
  def import
    card_id = params[:card]
    card = CreditCard.find_by(id: card_id)
    pay_to_pot = params[:cardPot]
    purchases = params[:purchases]
    purchases.each do |p|
      purchase_params = p.permit(:description, :amount, :transaction_date, :statement_reference, :statement_description).merge({user_id: 1, credit_card_id: card_id})
      new_purchase = Purchase.create(purchase_params)
      p[:reimbursements].each do |r|
        start_date = p[:start_date] || Date.today
        instalments = p[:spread] ? card.free_months_remaining : 1
        Reimbursement.create({purchase_id: new_purchase.id, instalments: instalments, user_id: 1, pay_to_pot_id: pay_to_pot, pay_from_pot_id: r[:pot], total_amount: p[:amount], start_date: start_date })
      end
    end
  end
```

This gets the desired effect but it feels like I could be doing this more efficiently, and/or that it's not the standard convention. I could create all of the purchase entities without needing to do an `each`, but then I would need some way to create the reimbursements and link them to the purchase ids

Note: obviously `user_id: 1` isn't going to be in production! Just a convenience while getting started.

Comment: Depend of you RoR version you could take a look to `upsert_all` method https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-upsert_all then you could do something like `card.purchases.upsert_all(params[:purchases])`

Comment: Thanks @Gaeguri ... once I have done the upsert_all, how would I then create the reimbursements? Plus for both the purchases and the reimbursements, there are certain params which are not present on the request which need to be added within the controller, so I think `params[: purchases]` would not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use [Active Record Nested Attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html), which should create associated relation.

Also for the custom params which are not present in request, you can add a before save callback on the respective model and set the value.